# Is there a gfortran equivalent to gcc's __attribute__((section("name")))?

Tags: gcc, methods, gnu, gfortran, annotate

I am using the nestedvm package, which includes a patched Gnu gcc compiler.  For this package, callable user methods/functions have to annotated with `__attribute__((section(".text")))`, as shown in the C example below.

```
void echo(const char *string, int count)  __attribute__((section(".text")));
void echo(const char *string, int count) {
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<count;i++)
        printf("%d: %s\n",i,string);
}
```

I don't know about the inner workings of the patched compiler, but without this annotation, the user function is not visible to outside callers.

If using gfortran, how can I accomplish this annotation for Fortran subroutines and functions?  Could this be done with a linker script file?  I could write a C wrapper to the Fortran functions, but would like to avoid this if possible.

** UPDATE 1 **
Using nm to investigate the .o file sheds some light on the issue...a C method without the attribute looks like the suckram function (which is not callable in nestedvm), while the echo function has the attribute and is callable in nestedvm:

```
Name                  Value   Class        Type         Size     Line  Section
suckram             |00000000|   T  |              FUNC|00000078|     |.text.suckram
echo                |00000200|   T  |              FUNC|00000074|     |.text
```

The test1 subroutine in my Fortran object looks like the suckram method without the attribute:

```
test1_              |00000000|   T  |              FUNC|00000080|     |.text.test1_
```

According to some nestedvm documentation I found, in order for a user function to be callable in nestedvm, it has to end up in the `.text` section.

** UPDATE 2 **
A link command line is below.  It is too long to put in a comment. I removed some of the many .o files (…)

`mips-unknown-elf-gfortran  -O3 -mmemcpy -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -falign-functions=512 -fno-rename-registers -fno-schedule-insns -fno-delayed-branch  -march=mips1 -specs=/home/jhuber/Documents/source/nestedvm/upstream/install/mips-unknown-elf/lib/crt0-override.spec -I. -Wall -Wno-unused  -o build/refprop/Refprop.mips build/refprop/NVM.o (...) build/refprop/TRNS_VIS.o build/refprop/MAIN.o -march=mips1 -specs=/home/jhuber/Documents/source/nestedvm/upstream/install/mips-unknown-elf/lib/crt0-override.spec --static -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,-Map=output1.map -Wl,--cref -lc -Wl,-Map=output.map -Wl,--cref`

Also, even though I am calling the code as a library, nestedvm requires the library to have a MAIN routine for initialization.  If I make some dummy calls to the library functions in the MAIN routine, those functions that are called in MAIN are moved the `.text` section, and become callable.

** UPDATE 3 ** 
Verbose output from make.  I removed some of the many .o files (…)

`mips-unknown-elf-gfortran  -O3 -mmemcpy -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -falign-functions=512 -fno-rename-registers -fno-schedule-insns -fno-delayed-branch  -march=mips1 -specs=/home/jhuber/Documents/source/nestedvm/upstream/install/mips-unknown-elf/lib/crt0-override.spec -I. -Wall -Wno-unused  -o build/refprop/Refprop.mips build/refprop/NVM.o (…) build/refprop/TRNS_VIS.o build/refprop/MAIN.o -march=mips1 -specs=/home/jhuber/Documents/source/nestedvm/upstream/install/mips-unknown-elf/lib/crt0-override.spec --static -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,-Map=output1.map -Wl,--cref -lc -Wl,-Map=output.map -Wl,--cref -v`

`Driving: mips-unknown-elf-gfortran -O3 -mmemcpy -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -falign-functions=512 -fno-rename-registers -fno-schedule-insns -fno-delayed-branch -march=mips1 -specs=/home/jhuber/Documents/source/nestedvm/upstream/install/mips-unknown-elf/lib/crt0-override.spec -I. -Wall -Wno-unused -o build/refprop/Refprop.mips build/refprop/NVM.o (…) build/refprop/TRNS_VIS.o build/refprop/MAIN.o -march=mips1 -specs=/home/jhuber/Documents/source/nestedvm/upstream/install/mips-unknown-elf/lib/crt0-override.spec --static -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,-Map=output1.map -Wl,--cref -lc -Wl,-Map=output.map -Wl,--cref -v -l gfortran -l m`

`Using built-in specs.
Reading specs from /home/jhuber/Documents/source/nestedvm/upstream/install/mips-unknown-elf/lib/crt0-override.spec
Reading specs from /home/jhuber/Documents/source/nestedvm/upstream/install/mips-unknown-elf/lib/crt0-override.spec
COLLECT_GCC=mips-unknown-elf-gfortran
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/home/jhuber/Documents/source/nestedvm/upstream/install/libexec/gcc/mips-unknown-elf/4.8.5/lto-wrapper
Target: mips-unknown-elf
Configured with: ../gcc-4.8.5/configure --prefix=/home/jhuber/Documents/source/nestedvm/upstream/install --target=mips-unknown-elf --disable-threads --disable-libssp --with-gnu-ld --with-gnu-as --with-newlib=yes --enable-sjlj-exceptions --enable-languages=c : (reconfigured) ../gcc-4.8.5/configure --prefix=/home/jhuber/Documents/source/nestedvm/upstream/install --target=mips-unknown-elf --disable-threads --disable-libssp --with-gnu-ld --with-gnu-as --with-newlib=yes --enable-sjlj-exceptions --enable-languages=c --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran
Thread model: single
gcc version 4.8.5 (GCC) 
Reading specs from /home/jhuber/Documents/source/nestedvm/upstream/install/lib/gcc/mips-unknown-elf/4.8.5/../../../../mips-unknown-elf/lib/libgfortran.spec
rename spec lib to liborig
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-O3' '-mmemcpy' '-ffunction-sections' '-fdata-sections' '-falign-functions=512' '-fno-rename-registers' '-fno-schedule-insns' '-fno-delayed-branch' '-march=mips1' '-specs=/home/jhuber/Documents/source/nestedvm/upstream/install/mips-unknown-elf/lib/crt0-override.spec' '-I' '.' '-Wall' '-Wno-unused' '-o' 'build/refprop/Refprop.mips' '-march=mips1' '-specs=/home/jhuber/Documents/source/nestedvm/upstream/install/mips-unknown-elf/lib/crt0-override.spec' '-static' '-v'
COMPILER_PATH=/home/jhuber/Documents/source/nestedvm/upstream/install/libexec/gcc/mips-unknown-elf/4.8.5/:/home/jhuber/Documents/source/nestedvm/upstream/install/libexec/gcc/mips-unknown-elf/4.8.5/:/home/jhuber/Documents/source/nestedvm/upstream/install/libexec/gcc/mips-unknown-elf/:/home/jhuber/Documents/source/nestedvm/upstream/install/lib/gcc/mips-unknown-elf/4.8.5/:/home/jhuber/Documents/source/nestedvm/upstream/install/lib/gcc/mips-unknown-elf/:/home/jhuber/Documents/source/nestedvm/upstream/install/lib/gcc/mips-unknown-elf/4.8.5/../../../../mips-unknown-elf/bin/
LIBRARY_PATH=/home/jhuber/Documents/source/nestedvm/upstream/install/lib/gcc/mips-unknown-elf/4.8.5/:/home/jhuber/Documents/source/nestedvm/upstream/install/lib/gcc/mips-unknown-elf/4.8.5/../../../../mips-unknown-elf/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-O3' '-mmemcpy' '-ffunction-sections' '-fdata-sections' '-falign-functions=512' '-fno-rename-registers' '-fno-schedule-insns' '-fno-delayed-branch' '-march=mips1' '-specs=/home/jhuber/Documents/source/nestedvm/upstream/install/mips-unknown-elf/lib/crt0-override.spec' '-I' '.' '-Wall' '-Wno-unused' '-o' 'build/refprop/Refprop.mips' '-march=mips1' '-specs=/home/jhuber/Documents/source/nestedvm/upstream/install/mips-unknown-elf/lib/crt0-override.spec' '-static' '-v'
 /home/jhuber/Documents/source/nestedvm/upstream/install/libexec/gcc/mips-unknown-elf/4.8.5/collect2 -EB -o build/refprop/Refprop.mips /home/jhuber/Documents/source/nestedvm/upstream/install/lib/gcc/mips-unknown-elf/4.8.5/crti.o /home/jhuber/Documents/source/nestedvm/upstream/install/lib/gcc/mips-unknown-elf/4.8.5/crtbegin.o /home/jhuber/Documents/source/nestedvm/upstream/install/lib/gcc/mips-unknown-elf/4.8.5/../../../../mips-unknown-elf/lib/crt0.o -L/home/jhuber/Documents/source/nestedvm/upstream/install/lib/gcc/mips-unknown-elf/4.8.5 -L/home/jhuber/Documents/source/nestedvm/upstream/install/lib/gcc/mips-unknown-elf/4.8.5/../../../../mips-unknown-elf/lib build/refprop/NVM.o (…) build/refprop/TRNS_VIS.o build/refprop/MAIN.o --gc-sections -Map=output1.map --cref -lc -Map=output.map --cref -lgfortran -lm -lgcc -lm -lgcc -lgcc /home/jhuber/Documents/source/nestedvm/upstream/install/lib/gcc/mips-unknown-elf/4.8.5/crtend.o /home/jhuber/Documents/source/nestedvm/upstream/install/lib/gcc/mips-unknown-elf/4.8.5/crtn.o`

Comment: Can you show your command line? Those section names look at first glance to be the result of `-ffunction-sections`, so you can maybe just leave off that flag.

Comment: I dont know anything about fortran specifically, but generally that stuff should all be in the .text section and callable ... you probably need a way to declare it in some FFI method in fortran... I did some googling and found a module called: iso_c_binding... in other languages I have done in this in you generally link to a C library rather than compiling everything into one executable from the get go... (the C library could still potentially be statically linked)

Answer (score 0):

I did some local tests, and `-ffunction-sections` puts each fortran function its own section, as expected. Compare:

```
$ gfortran -c -O3 -o hello.o hello.f90
$ objdump -h hello.o 

hello.o:     file format elf64-x86-64

Sections:
Idx Name          Size      VMA               LMA               File off  Algn
  0 .text         000000aa  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  00000040  2**4
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, RELOC, READONLY, CODE
  1 .data         00000000  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  000000ea  2**0
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
  2 .bss          00000000  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  000000ea  2**0
                  ALLOC
  3 .rodata.str1.1 0000000a  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  000000ea  2**0
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  4 .text.startup 00000026  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  00000100  2**4
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, RELOC, READONLY, CODE
  5 .rodata       0000001c  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  00000130  2**4
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  6 .comment      00000026  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  0000014c  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY
  7 .note.GNU-stack 00000000  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  00000172  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY
  8 .eh_frame     00000068  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  00000178  2**3
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, RELOC, READONLY, DATA
```

to:

```
$ gfortran -ffunction-sections -c -O3 -o hello.o hello.f90
$ objdump -h hello.o 

hello.o:     file format elf64-x86-64

Sections:
Idx Name          Size      VMA               LMA               File off  Algn
  0 .text         00000000  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  00000040  2**0
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE
  1 .data         00000000  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  00000040  2**0
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
  2 .bss          00000000  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  00000040  2**0
                  ALLOC
  3 .rodata.str1.1 0000000a  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  00000040  2**0
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  4 .text.MAIN__  00000097  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  00000050  2**4
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, RELOC, READONLY, CODE
  5 .text.foo_    0000000a  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  000000f0  2**4
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE
  6 .text.startup.main 00000026  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  00000100  2**4
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, RELOC, READONLY, CODE
  7 .rodata       0000001c  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  00000130  2**4
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  8 .comment      00000026  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  0000014c  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY
  9 .note.GNU-stack 00000000  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  00000172  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY
 10 .eh_frame     00000068  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  00000178  2**3
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, RELOC, READONLY, DATA
```

The builtin linker script on my local machine rolls all of these into `.text` by default. It appears whatever you're linking with doesn't. You should be able to modify that script to do what you're trying. It's a bit more difficult than the attribute extensions, since you'll have to maintain the list in a separate file, but you should be able to locate things however you like. I can work up an example here if you give some more context about that in your question.

Comment: Thanks Carl!  long-story-short: nestedvm uses a patched gcc compiler/linker to create a MIPS binary that it then translates to Java bytecode.  `-ffunction-sections` is required by nestedvm, along with a number of other compiler and linker flags.  Changing these required flags breaks nestedvm.

Comment: Can you show me a link command line? Add a `-v` to one of those command lines and it should drop out somewhere.

Comment: I updated the original post with a link command line.  It was too long to put in a comnment.

Comment: I meant the command line to the linker itself. What you put does eventually invoke the linker, but through the compiler driver as the front-end. Can you add a `-v` to what you put there and show the command that actually does the link?